# 'OR' statement in Python evaluates to True even if the condition is false

Tags: python-3.x

This logical OR evaluates to true even if I am providing any other value apart from 1,2 or 3 .

Please help with this question as i am beginning to learn Python

```
user_input=int(input('Please provide Size of coffee: (1-small/2-medium/3-large)'))
if user_input!=1 or user_input!=2 or user_input!=3:
    print('Please input 1,2 or 3')
```

Comment: That's because 4 is not equal to 1,2 or 3. Also your condition will be true for any integer as well. Instead, you want to check `if not (user_input == 1 or user_input == 2 or user_input == 3`

Comment: The only way your condition is ever False is if you can provide input that is equal to 1, 2, and 3 at the same time. In other words: (x!=1 or x!=2) is a tautology

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
user_input=int(input('Please provide Size of coffee: (1-small/2-medium/3-large)'))
if user_input not in (1, 2, 3):
    print('Please input 1,2 or 3')
else:
    print('Thanks... {} coming up'.format(user_input))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using NOR operation in your program so where multiple TRUEs equate to False. The correct operation in this case is NAND. Hope this helps you.

```js
user_input=int(input('Please provide Size of coffee: (1-small/2-medium/3-large)'))
if user_input!=1 and user_input!=2 and user_input!=3:
    print('Please input 1,2 or 3')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you have implemented the logical check operation, you have connected your logic using an OR operator which evaluates to TRUE even if one of the input is TRUE. In the current implementation lets assume that the user is going to type 2, so as per your code, statements user_input!=1 and user_input!=3 will evaluate to TRUE and user_input!=2 evaluates to FALSE and since you have connected using logical OR operator your output will be TRUE since OR (TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) => TRUE. So the correct implementation would be

```
user_input=int(input('Please provide Size of coffee: (1-small/2-medium/3-large)'))
acceptable_values = (1,2,3)
if user_input not in acceptable_values:
    print('Please input 1,2 or 3')
```